# HDD Partitions Management

Tags: partitioning

My Acer E5 511 has HDD with five basic partitions as will be seen from enclosed image.  After upgrading to Windows 10, the recovery partition of the size of more than 16 GB is lying empty.  It is not visible  under "My PC" and presumably is hidden.  My question is can I use it for storing data and if yes how?

[[image: Snip of my Disk Management Window][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9hbu.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" ? Did you open it ?

Comment: I think he meant the columns `Free Space` and `% Free`, which apparently consists of bogus values for unmounted drives.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the recovery partition is really empty first (or at least, that it has no recovery image that you may want to preserve, which should at least occupy around 3GB of the partition).

To do that, you can assign a drive letter to the partition with `diskpart`:

[image]

Make sure you pick the correct recovery partition (since you have two) when enter `select volume N`.

Once you've confirmed that, you can remove the drive letter with `remove all` and delete the partition with `delete volume`. Then you may either create a new partition with the space released or extend your `My Documents (D:)` to the end of the disk with `Disk Management`. Just right click on either the `Unallocated` space or `My Documents (D:)` and you'll see your available options.

Comment: Thanks Mr Tom Yan for stopping me from making a fool of myself.  I proceeded as per your advice mounted the partition and found out that it is in fact OEM Partition containing files for factory reset when needed.